# Increasing current in circuit

Tags: current, voltage-regulator, switching-regulator

I'm fairly new to circuit design, so excuse me for asking maybe a noob question; I did some research, but because of my lack of understanding I'm not quite sure if my conclusion is the right one.

I have a simple circuit with a high voltage input (24 V), a step down converter with components ([XL1509](http://www.xlsemi.com/datasheet/XL1509%20datasheet-English.pdf) 3.3 V), and an ESP32.

When I read the datasheet of the XL1509, I read the minimum current is 0.2 A. Running the ESP32, the current necessary is below this 0.2 A.

My question:

How can I increase the current to at least 0.2 A, so the step-down converter will work properly? I think I need like a 16.5 Ω resistor (3.3/0.2). Is this a correct assumption?

My second question regarding this: I'm not married to the XL1509, an other step-down converter will also do, but all step-down converters that can go from 24 V to 3.3 V have a minimum load of 0.2 A. Am I missing something?

And, is, for the above circuit (efficiency wise) a linear regulator maybe a better idea? The ESP32 is the only component (besides the regulator and its assisting components) in my circuit.

Comment: _"XL1509 I read the minimum current is 0.2A"_ Poor design. Get another converter?

Comment: You should supply a link to the datasheet where you found this information regarding minimum load. I have never seen a step down converter that specifies a minimum load to work.

Comment: 24-3.3= 20.7 * 0.2= 4.14 power dissipation. I don't think you should use linear regulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0.2 A mentioned in the datasheet on page 6 (the only mention I could find) is one of the test parameters of the testing circuit they used for measurements.

Lower currents may give other testing outcomes, but the 0.2 A is not a specified minimum load, and not a specified limitation of the XL1509.

DC/DC converters that need a minimum load to function properly do exist, but as far as I read it, the datasheet doesn't say the XL1509 is one of them.

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood this part.

Comment: The implication is that it may regulate less well at lower currents; at the very least, you will want to test this.

Comment: There is a reason why the specs are worse at light loads as I mentioned on deaf ears in my answer

Comment: The stability margin is not determined by the IC or switch alone but in the linear case is a function of Q =X(f)/(RdsOn+DCR+ESR) when there is no load to dampen it.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, your assumption is correct.

I don't have the datasheet but simple converters often had a 10% output preload for improved stability specs, as this load provides some damping to the high series RLC switch.

**Stability is a spec. parameter for overshoot, when there are step load changes in current.**

This can be precluded with Differential error compensation gain (think PI**D**) perhaps at the compromise for ripple or some other method of feedback or forward conversion.